# Running Apache with Tomcat

Tags: apache-httpd, java, tomcat

I was wondering if it's possible to run a Tomcat server within Apache whilst also running PHP servers under other virtual host instances? And if so, how is this done?

Basically, I'm trying to run an Apache server that redirects to different applications based on the DNS address used. For example:

www.javaapp.com -> Sends the Java application to the clients browser

and

www.phpapp.com -> Sends a PHP application to the clients browser

And I was also wondering if there's a way of adding a third application in RoR as well, and whether Apache can serve Rails or not?

I am currently using Tomcat for my JSP application, I know this can be integrated with Apache, but I wasn't sure if it could be done alongside applications written in other languages. As I know that Apache is able to redirect to virtual hosts based on the DNS address entered, which I thought was pretty cool and would really help me to host multiple applications on my box that I'm writing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can proxy the requests from Apache to Tomcat as described in 
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/proxy-howto.html. Basically you need something like this in your apache config:

```
ProxyPass         /myapp  http://localhost:8081/myapp
ProxyPassReverse  /myapp  http://localhost:8081/myapp
```

The same method should work too with Rails as long as you access your applications with a unique prefix like `/myapp` above.

If you want to proxy the whole virtual server (e.g. `ProxyPass /  http://localhost:8081/myapp`), then the information in http://www.humboldt.co.uk/2009/02/the-mystery-of-proxypassreverse.html might be useful to keep redirects working.

Comment: Is there any sort of dummies guide to do this, I've been trying to do what you said for the past 2 hours or so with no luck, and I'm ready to kill myself. The guides aren't dumbed down enough for me I think, haha. I was running straight from the Tomcat server previously on port 80, but now I just want to redirect through apache to the tomcat server.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know any guide. Perhaps you can describe where you're stuck. First Tomcat should work when accessed directly on the new port. Then Apache should work on port 80. Test without redirecting first. Then enable the proxy. If you get an internal server error try to find the matching log entry

Comment: Another simple example: http://gerrydevstory.com/2013/06/29/tomcat-apache-reverse-proxy/

Comment: I just tried the simple example you gave, with Tomcat running on port :8080 and this is the error I get when I type the DNS in from the server:

~"Service Temporarily Unavailable

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at www.mydns.co.uk Port 80"

Comment: Is `www.mydns.co.uk:8080` working? Can you get the apache error logs?

Comment: Yes it is working. How do I get the logs? Sorry, I don't use apache much, it usually just works.

Comment: Probably `/var/log/httpd/error_log` - otherwise look for `ErrorLog` in the Apache config

Comment: This is the error I seem to be getting in the error log:

[Fri Nov 08 23:01:33 2013] [error] (13)Permission denied: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (localhost) failed
[Fri Nov 08 23:01:33 2013] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (localhost)

Comment: Okay, just managed to get it working, it appears SELinux was causing issues....doe! Thanks buddy, appreciate the help :)